# multithreading on graphics GDI+

Tags: .net, multithreading, graphics

I made some tests in GDI+ with drawing lines/arcs, on a graphics 
class created  .FromImage method.

For performance reasons, I divide this in a multithreading setup 
(tests with several methods: New Thread(AddressOf.. or Parallel.For... or New Task..)
 I have noticed that this gives no performance increase.
However if I am replacing the .Graphics.DrawPath routine by a test routine (for example: calculations) then there is a real improvement in performance when using multithreading
 (see figures)
What is the reason for this and how to solve?

I have created four setups:

1. drawing on graphics:
   4x (40000 elements on a seperate graphics.fromimage) on 4 threads (or task )
   (time: 1s 76msec)
2. drawing on graphics:
   4x (40000 elements on a seperate graphics.fromimage)  serial 
   (time: 959msec)
3. calculation:
   4x (floating point test calculation) on 4 threads (or task ) 
   (time: 672msec)
4. calculation:
   4x (floating point test calculation)  serial 
   (time: 2s 189msec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any large library that's thread-safe uses locks to protect shared state.  These locks often cause contention between threads, a thread will get bogged down waiting for another thread to release the lock.

This is [Ahmdal's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahmdal%27s_Law) at work.

Comment: i understand ahmdal's law regarding setup 3&4, but regarding setup 1&2  is there a way to work around?

Comment: You've got that backwards.  No, you cannot alter the locking code in GDI+.

Comment: so drawing is always going via the gpu, even for bitmaps?